# Add requestmapping anotation in my spring mvc project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

[image]

when I was trying to add requestmapping annotation it got an error in the project .When I added
`import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;`

got an another error.

```
package com.example.demo.controller.user;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("Home")
public class HomeController {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the spring-web and spring-webmvc dependency mentioned in your pom.xml? If no then you have to add the same in pom.xml as dependencies.

You can refer the pom.xml from here: https://o7planning.org/en/10865/simple-crud-example-with-spring-mvc-restful-web-service

Comment: when updated dependencies.It Worked.Happy learning.plz up quate my question.